# Need to get HTML Element's Layout information just like Firefox's debugger

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have a aspx.net grid control and i'm trying to copy the grid control's first row information into another table java script.
I'm getting width of each cell by parsing through the grid control's first row using the following code:

gridCtrl.rows[0].cells[x].clientWidth

where x is 1 to last cell

But some how the width doesn't match the width display by Firefox's layout width.

I tried debugging Firefox debugger and explored all the attributes to see if i mix match margin, padding, width etc to get the width displayed by the Firefox's Layout width.
But so far no luck.

I'm wonder any of the experts in the field could provide some help.

I'm looking for Something similar to the layout information provided by the Firefox debugger. 
I want to get individual elements like
elements margin, border, padding and the actual width of element.

[Sorry since this is my first post i'm not allowed to post a pic, But if you open fire fox browser and hit F12 and select HTML/Layout. you will see the layout information i'm talking about]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I must post as a reply :(.

I think that the problem is that the element might have a width set initially, let's say 50px, but it can also adjust based on the amount of text in it. In this case, you should not get the rendered dimension because that one differs from browser to browser.

Also another problem that is see is if the element has a min-width and dynamic width based on the viewport's size. In this case it would not work either.

If I am correct your solution would be to write a JavaScript code that sends you the information.

Comment: THanks Gabriel Cliseru,

Comment: Your are right, The text is getting added dynamically. I'm try to write java script that will provide me the dynamic width but i'm struck as I'm not able to figure out what attribute/ property to use to get the dynamic width. I'm sure there is a way because the browsers are able to get those dynamic reading. If you get a chance Could you please provide sample  javascript. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can get that with document.querySelector(css selector).offsetWidth or offsetHeight or by using jQuery